Why does 2x - x == x in IEEE floating point precision?
I would expect this to only hold when the last bit of the mantissa is 0. Otherwise, in order to subtract them (since their exponents differ by 1), x would lose a bit of precision first and the result would either end up being rounded up or down.
But a quick experiment shows that it seems to always hold (assuming x and 2x are finite) for any random number (including those with a a trailing 1 bit).
import random
import struct
from collections import Counter


def float_to_bits(f: float) -> int:
    """
    Convert a double-precision floating-point number to a 64-bit integer.
    """
    # Pack the float into 8 bytes, then unpack as an unsigned 64-bit integer
    return struct.unpack(">Q", struct.pack(">d", f))[0]


def check_floating_point_precision(num_trials: int) -> float:
    true_count = 0
    false_count = 0
    bit_counts = Counter()

    for _ in range(num_trials):
        x = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if 2 * x - x == x:
            true_count += 1
        else:
            false_count += 1

        bits = float_to_bits(x)

        # Extract the last three bits of the mantissa
        last_three_bits = bits & 0b111
        bit_counts[last_three_bits] += 1

    return (bit_counts, true_count / num_trials)


num_trials = 1_000_000
(bit_counts, proportion_true) = check_floating_point_precision(num_trials)

print(f"The proportion of times 2x - x == x holds true: {proportion_true:.6f}")
print("Distribution of last three bits (mod 8):")
for bits_value in range(8):
    print(f"{bits_value:03b}: {bit_counts[bits_value]} occurrences")

The proportion of times 2x - x == x holds true: 1.000000
Distribution of last three bits (mod 8):
000: 312738 occurrences
001: 62542 occurrences
010: 125035 occurrences
011: 62219 occurrences
100: 187848 occurrences
101: 62054 occurrences
110: 125129 occurrences
111: 62435 occurrences


Does it also show this behavior when 2*x and x are coming from function calls? One could assume, that 2*x - x == x might maybe get optimized by the compiler.

Would a compiler "optimization" change the actual value of the output? That seems bad

For the magnitudes of values you are working with, multiplying by 2 only changes the exponent without changing the mantissa. Subtraction of nearly equal values can result in a loss of precision, but 2*x is an order of magnitude greater than x.

@chepner Please read the description. I would expect that difference of 1 in the exponent to matter when talking about floating point equality. I find that 4x - 3x seems to equal x about half the time (that is 4x - 3x has the behavior I expected from 2x - x). It looks as if subtraction has one more bit of precision than the mantissa and I was hoping someone could confirm this or point me to a resource or something

@Progman I see you added the python tag to this question. Are python floats not just the standard IEEE-754 double-precision floating point numbers that every language uses?

Btw, could anyone explain why my question is getting downvoted so much?

@dspyz Technically, Python makes no promises about float; it's whatever floating-point types are provided by the underlying platform. In practice, I've never seen something that didn't provide IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic.

You might see more variation if you don't restrict yourself to values between 0 and 1; try a different unit interval starting with much larger values, for example. (You aren't uniformly sampling the real numbers between 0 and 1.)

I recommend you add in the example that shows a differnt result for 4*x - 3*x as that results in about 60% match rather than 100%.

@JonSG My gut says it's actually 50% and the reason it looks like 60 is because it turns out Python's random.uniform isn't all that uniform in the lowest order bits

If we had to do arithmetic only in the floating-point format, even for internal values during the arithmetic, then, yes, 2*x - x would not always yield x. For example, with four-bit significands, we could have:



Expression
Value/Calculation




x
1.001•20 (9)


2*x
1.001•21 (18)


2*x - x
1.001•21 − 1.001•20  = 1.001•21 − 0.100•21 (shifted right operand and lost a bit)  = 0.101•21 = 1.010•20 (10).



However, that is not how floating-point implementations work. To get the right results, they use either more digits internally or more sophisticated algorithms or both. IEEE-754 specifies that the result of an elementary operation is the value you would get by computing the exact real-number arithmetic result with no error or rounding or limitations on digits and then rounding that real number to the nearest value representable in the destination format, using the rounding rule in effect for the operation. (Most commonly, that rounding rule is to round to the nearest value, breaking ties in favor of the one with an even low digit in its significand.)
A consequence of this requirement is that, if the mathematical result is representable in the format, the computed result must be that mathematical result. When the mathematical result is representable, there is never any rounding error in a properly implemented elementary operation.

Does this explain why 2x -x == x is always true while 4x - 3x == x is only true about 60% of the time? I don't know if it does or not. If so, that is cool but it might be even better to show why the second example fails

@JonSG: The scale of the numbers is irrelevant for floating-point as long as it is within the bounds of the format. The examples would work the same if you multiplied them all by 1024 or 1/512 or other powers of two. The reason 4*x - 3*x will not always produce x is because 3•x is not always representable, so sometimes 3*x will have some rounding error. Then 4*x - 3*x may not produce x because it is not computing 4•x−3•x but is computing 4•x−y, where y is some number near but not equal to 3•x.

Ah, so x is always represented as "some float valueand2xand4xcan always be represented correctly as they are powers of 2 multiplied by something that is a float while3x` cannot always be represented correctly and must sometimes be rounded to the nearest float. That sound right?

@JonSG: Yes, for binary floating-point, 2•x and 4•x are always representable. (For other bases, possibly not. For example, with 4-digit decimal, 7.003 is representable, but 2•7.003 = 14.006 is not representable, since that requires 5 digits. Multiplying by the base always has a representable result, so 10•7.003 = 70.03 only needs 4 digits and is representable.)

Always representable until you hit overflow, anyway.

When you do the arithmetic by hand, you’ll see why this always holds. Yes, in the least significant bits you’re sometimes doing xyz10 - wxyz1. But you’re also subtracting away the most significant bit, so there’s room for the full precision at the bottom. This property is known as Sterbenz’s lemma. (That link gives a longer and more formal proof.)

Let x and y be the real values represented by the floats x and 2*x. Multiplying by 2 is exact: the mantissa stays the same, just the exponent increases by 1. So y = 2x. Then you subtract. Float subtraction can't always result in the real difference, as that might not be representable as float. But it's specified to give the closest value that is representable as float (or a closest in case of ties). And here, the real difference is y-x = 2x-x = x, and that is representable as float, as that's the x that we started with.
In your other case 4*x - 3*x, multiplying by 4 is again exact (the exponent simply gets increased by 2). But multiplying by 3 generally isn't. When the mantissa is odd, multiplying by 3 would require one more bit in the new mantissa. That bit is lost, you get a float whose value is either slightly smaller or slightly larger than 3 times the value of x. So when you then subtract, one of the two values might already be "inaccurate". The subtraction then might also lead to an "inaccurate" overall result, or the subtraction might be inaccurate as well and happen to cancel out the earlier inaccuracy, so that you happen to get exactly x. But the problem is the 3*x, not the subtraction. When 3*x is exact as well, then just like in the 2*x - x case, all operations are exact and the overall result is exactly x.
How is subtraction able to do the calculation so that the result is the closest float-representable value? I think usually with some extra bits or cleverness during the calculation. But I don't think the standard defines how implementations shall calculate the corrected result, it just cares *that" they do.
